# How do I find the power x in this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

How do I find $x$ in this  $$2^{2x} + 2^x+2 = 2^4\ ?$$
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Put $2^x=y$ and write the new equation.

Comment: Let $y=2^x$.  Then solve the resulting quadratic.

Answer (score 2):

Use the changement of variable $y=2^x$.

Then you end up with

$$y^2+y+2=2^4=16$$

so

$$y^2+y-14=0.$$

I think you can take it from here.